# How to update git submodules in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, git-submodules

I'm trying to build this project at "https://github.com/jonasoreland/runnerup" on Android Studio. But when I'm going to compile it I received this error:

[image]

I think it's because I've to update git submodules like said on a page project where is specified to Run the following command to get all submodules:

```
git submodule init && git submodule update
```

But I'm new with git and I don't know how to do this.
I ask you if you can explain me step by step how to do this.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 4):

you can try this git command

```
git submodule update --recursive --init
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jonasoreland/runnerup.git ./runnerup
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Option2

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/jonasoreland/runnerup.git ./runnerup
```

For more details on submodule: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule